# MySQL error 1064 when using default expressions

Tags: mysql

A MySQL 8.0.12 instance I'm working with seems incapable of defining tables with default expressions.

I've pasted the code straight from documentation and I'm getting the error 1064 unless I remove the default expressions and replace them with literal defaults.

I'm aware that some engines are supposed to not support all default expressions, but the error code is supposed to be different ( ER_UNSUPPORTED_ACTION_ON_DEFAULT_VAL_GENERATED, 3774).

Is there a server option that I didn't find that turns off the default expressions and allows only literals?

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  -- literal defaults
  i INT         DEFAULT 0,
  c VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '',
  -- expression defaults
  f FLOAT       DEFAULT (RAND() * RAND()),
  b BINARY(16)  DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())),
  d DATE        DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 YEAR),
  p POINT       DEFAULT (Point(0,0)),
  j JSON        DEFAULT (JSON_ARRAY())
);
```

Comment: You can't have SQL expressions as default values in MySQL.. If you want to simulate this you need to use generated columns (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) or update with triggers.

Comment: The syntax error-generating code I've pasted is taken straight from the MySQL reference manual here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: Okay then they added a new feature to MySQL 8 this week (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html) it seams you sure you are running the minimal MySQL version of MySQL 8.0.13 like the manual says?

Comment: My bad, I've just checked the release notes and indeed default expressions are only supported from version .13. I didn't suspect such a substantial feature would be added between one point version and another...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion from @Raymond Niljand, I've just checked the release notes and indeed default expressions are only supported from version .13.

Reading the CREATE TABLE documentation, I didn't suspect I was looking at a 3-day old feature, and that such a substantial feature would be added between one point version and another...